# How to trigger a running windows form app?

Tags: c++

I have a windows form app (C++) that generates a set of PDF files by using 3rd party software - which creates the PDF files with the provided info from the app.

The question is : How do I suspend the app in a way that it will wait for all
the PDF files to be generated before generating a new set of files?

I figured that I should make a loop that will check for the amount of PDF files in a specific directory. if the amount of files equals to the amount
there should be, the loop will be broken and the code continues.
Just not sure how to do that...

For the record I'm not a programmer, I'm an electrical engineer so
my knowledge of programming comes down to some basic C++ ...

Comment: If the other application has a window open that either disappears or changes its title to a certain value when it is done, you could use FindWindow to track progress.

Comment: Or maybe that application has some Api, or even simply an exit code when it is done? Which application is it?

Comment: I don't think that I have enough experience to pull off complicated tasks, as I said, I'm not a programmer I'm an electrical engineer, the 3rd party program is AutoCAD. I have no Idea how to tap into it's code and track the exit code of the PDF creation process. At best I can somehow understand how to check for the obvious output...

Comment: Well, you do tell Autocad to generate those PDFs, right?

Comment: Yes, of course, they appear in the assigned directory I choose. I said that I thought about creating a "while" loop with exit condition for the amount of PDF files which I know how many there should be. I'm not sure how to do that, the main problem is that I don't know how to get all the file names from the directory...

Comment: Can you add some comments or code lines to illustrate how did you generate files by AutoCAD? Maybe you need to create a thread to do the file generation work and anther thread to check the files counter or something else to get you want.

Comment: You know, if you are using a `while` to generate a lots of files in main thread, the GUI will be locked and no chance to deal with messages sent from forms of app.

Comment: If you're using `CreateProcess` to start Autocad you can wait for it to exit.

Comment: The generation of the PDF files is made via the internal CMD embedded in the AutoCAD itself. The program (AutoCAD) uses LISP (code language like C++), it can accept a .SCR file (script) which contains the instructions. My app generates a script and introduce it to AutoCAD by using "system" to open the EXE of the AutoCAD and start the .SCR file, in return, the AutoCAD generate PDF files. That app summarises my understanding and knowledge in programming...

Comment: All I need is a code example, how to get all file names from a specific directory...